# Is it possible to perform surgery on your own spine?

Tags: internal-consistency, science-fiction, survival

My character has to perform surgery on herself and by herself.

She has all the surgery tools and a screen to watch what she is doing.

She is in a clean stable environment and there is no risk of infection.

She has to perform surgery near her spine, where she's inserting a microchip connecting to the nerve connected to the brain. The technology is futuristic so this is possible.

What I'm specifically asking if she could actually do the surgery?

Comment: Moving your hands in your back is quite difficult so performing a surgery in your spine will be even more... Does it requires anaesthesia? If it does it's quite probable she won't be able to do it... she may fall asleep. Also, you must think how much complicate is the procces? Just inject a a microcrip may be really easy, but that isn't the same as connecting each nerve from the spine to the chip.

Comment: What level is the rest of the technology? Does she have something that allows her the impossible reach to get to the section near her spinal column? How is she at the sight of blood? What about her blood? (It makes a difference to some.) Does she have sufficient blood for transfusion to reduce risk of dying on the table? Why is she doing it on herself instead of guiding someone (which would be significantly easier and lower-risk in this case)?

Comment: she is a genius who is mental. she doesnt really have emotions so she doesn't get grossed out. the technology is self made and is superior to modern science.

Comment: I have serious doubts that anyone, even a skilled surgeon, could perform surgery on their own spine.

Comment: Depending on size of microchip - could it simply be injected like a pet microchip? those are size of large grain of rice. Injecting something is far more achievable and believable than self-surgery

Comment: She would need remote manipulators to perform the surgery. What we now call a "surgical robot". She would also need to be a surgeon and an experienced one too. With the right technology it is within the bounds of possibility.

Comment: @RowynAlloway You should watch the self surgery scene in the movie Prometheus.

Comment: Obv not factual, but possibly realistic.. this scene from Master and Commander where the ship's surgeon removes a bullet from his own body. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f0cBrCTeis

Comment: this depends a lot on is she can see and reach the surgical site, she will definitely need mechanical assistance. Maybe a medical waldo.

Comment: It isn't clear what "can she actually do the surgery" means in this context (with the "technology is futuristic so it is possible"). You seem to have stipulated that it is possible, so what more is there to ask?

Comment: @Chromane -- No. A microchip can not just "be injected" into the spine like an ID chip. Just consider the relevant anatomy! An ID chip is a relatively autonomous thing. It just sits there. The chip in question needs to interact with the character's brain via nerves in the spinal cord.

Comment: @elemtilas So it is inserted in a reverse version of the [Spinal Tap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumbar_puncture). OP said in a comment further down that "you simple [sic] place the micro chip into your spine.". To me that implies that the chip does the whole 'connect to nerve tissue' thing by itself.

Comment: @Suthek -- I don't know what the OP's expertise is, but I'm guessing surgery isn't it. If the chip does all the work, then the question should be closed. If the technology is so advanced that the chip can integrate itself within the body, then "surgery" is not required and the question should be deleted as being senseless. Spinal tap isn't something you do on yourself either. Spinal tap isn't (really) a surgical procedure per se (it's an anesthesia thing, usually) so that's moot as far as the question goes.

Comment: Your character has human-like anatomy, I guess? Or could we assume more flexibility :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

No.

### Just no.

Not at all possible. Even with video. (One caveat only applies.) Even with futuristic technology. You're still dealing with the totally unfuturistic human body. And that's something the other autosurgery answers fail to deal with.

Human arms and hands aren't designed to work behind our backs all that well. Especially when away from direct visualisation. She will need not only finger dexterity to do this job but also main strength and range of motion that will be severely curtailed for hours.

Other answers have focused on abdominal / ventral autosurgeries. Yes, those are possible, and are relatively simple procedures: you can see what you're doing and are not putting strain on your arms and your hands are working in their natural anatomic position. A c-section takes something like 20 minutes. An appendectomy can take as little 5 minutes.

None of them address the specific needs of spine surgery. The kind of surgery your character will have to do will require several hours of preparation and actual work -- ***if she were an actual surgeon working in an actual hospital setting.*** I know you've accepted one of those answers, but the reality is that your scenario simply is not going to happen.

[image]

*This is a typical spinal surgery set-up.*

In order to access the nerves to connect the chip, your character will need to make an incision. Incisions bleed, so she will need to achieve hemostasis. She will need to carefully dissect through two or three inches of subcutaneous tissue: muscles, connective tissue. You know, stuff that she's going to need in order to move her body around after the procedure!

> [image]

*This is what it looks like when dissected down to the connective tissue on the spine itself.*

Once she gets down to bone, she'll still be a good inch to inch and a half away from the spinal cord itself. She will need a powered drill with several different kinds of specialised bits; she will need (quite literally!) a hammer and some chisels; she will need rongeurs. She's got to basically dig a hole through the bone in order to access the spinal cord.

> [image]

*Dem bones!*

Once she gets through the bone, she's going to be confronted by the *dura mater*, which is the layer of tissue that protects the spinal cord and contains her cerebrospinal fluid. This is the same layer of tissue and fluid that surrounds & bathes the brain. She's going to have to be very careful when dissecting bone off the dura. It's very easy to tear!

> [image]

*The dura.*

> [image]

*View of the spinal cord itself.*

Once she makes the incision through the dura, she'll at last be down to the spinal cord. Yay! ***That*** is the nerve that connects to her brain. Everything she's done so far is basically preparation for seating the implant. The "chip". At this point, she will have to know where in that mass of neurons is the appropriate nerve for the "chip" to be connected to. Easy-peasy!

Once the implant is in place, she's off the hook, right!?

Hell no!

She's still got to extricate herself from the situation. She has to close each and every layer that she just butchered in order to get down to the spinal cord. She will need to very carefully sew her own dura mater closed using extremely thin sutures and long specially designed needle holders.

Once that's done, she's gong to need to take all those bone chunks, mix them up with some blood and allograft bone chips in order to make a kind of bony bandage over the hole she made.

> [image]

*Stitches and glue.*

[image]

*Bone chips!!*

And then she'll have to secure the implant itself to her spine so it won't move around and come loose. She does **NOT** want to create a CSF leak where the "chip" attaches to her spinal cord! This will involve another drill which she'll use to shape a pocket in her spinal column so that the "chip" will have a secure home. And then a much smaller drill and a bunch of fiddly little screws to secure the implant to the bone.

[image]

*Screws!*

Then she'll have to close up the layers of muscle and tendons, subcutaneous layers and skin. If she's lucky, she'll end up with a nice little scar.

Basically, all you're asking your character to do is be not only an orthopedic surgeon (for the bone work) but also a neurosurgeon (for the nerve work and implantation) but to do all this whilst wide awake and alert! Sorry, but a little 0.5% novocaine is not going to get her through this.

Spine surgery is brutal. It requires great physical strength to do the dissections and to get through the bone. She can not do these things on herself.

You're also asking your character to be a surgical technologist. They're the ones that sort through all the thousands of surgical instruments, all the sizers, the drill bits, the fiddly little strings of suture to make all the surgeon's magic even possible.

[image]

*A Surgical Tech rocks the setup!*

And you want your girl to all this all by herself?

Super Woman couldn't do this all by herself!

McGyver couldn't do this all by himself!

Synopsis: there is no way in hell a single person can perform spinal surgery without help. She will most likely die on the table. You do not understand how close those drills and chisels are to the aorta and vena cava. A little slip will send something sharp right into a major vessel, and then she'll bleed out. If she doesn't kill herself outright, she will faint. Like I said, spine surgery is brutality. It is *physically brutal and barbaric*. She won't be able to put up with the hours of agonising pain that this will cause. I'm all for acupuncture, but I don't think that's going to help much. Since she can't be asleep to perform surgery, that leaves local anasthetics. There are serious side effects (including death) if she uses too much of that.

---

So, what's the one caveat that will allow her to accomplish all this?

Basically: **magic**. She can sit herself up against Handvavium LLC's  super-advanced robot and push the start button. Let the robot do all the work and she can watch it go from the screen. That's all there is to it!

But actual autosurgery? No. Not possible.

Comment: Thank you for posting the only sensible answer to this question!

Comment: Thanks, @JBH!  It was a fun answer to write.  Even with futuristic technology, barring some kind of robot that does **all** the hard work, the premise just doesn't make sense. Too many difficulties. Too much potential for terminal errors.

Comment: I feel like most of these images are better off as links with some sort of warning...

Comment: Point understood. However, the question regards surgery. "Warning" is rather assumed by query type in my opinion.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the "futuristic" setting can explain all of these difficulties away. Given the direction that surgical technology is progressing (specifically miniaturization and laparoscopy) it is not difficult to imagine that a futuristic spinal surgery would only require an insertion of a needle somewhere around the surgery site and then the rest being carried out through some sort of computer interface (maybe VR since this is the future).

Comment: @SamYonnou -- May be. Not really much point in asking the question, is there?

Comment: @SamYonnou Yes, we have surgeries today that require the tiniest incisions into which instruments are inserted.  You'd probably need a needle large enough to carry power and control to the nanotech, a saline line for irrigation, a thread line to feed the sutures, and a suction line that could handle those bone chips. The nanotech would have to cut those bone chips small enough to fit through the suction line.  It's all in Handwavium NanoMed's product brochure.

Comment: I've added spoiler tags around the graphic images, impressive answer though - have an upvote :D

Comment: Hey, I upvoted it the first time I saw it.  I gave what I thought was a good answer (and I still think it's a good one, for my skillset) but Elemtilas knows a lot more about this subject.  Unfortunately, the OP has not been clear about what the surgery is, where it is (which part of the back, where into the spine, etc), and how much future tech there is.  This makes every answer potentially good or bad, depending on how much it matches the OP's underlying conditions.

Comment: @MontyHarder If the OP upgrades their futuristic microchip for a Handwavium patented nanochip I don't see any problems with just injecting the chip into their bloodstream from their arm and having it find its own way to the correct implant location in the spine. Since it is a "nano"-chip it wouldn't need to actually make any incisions in the tissues around the spine that are wider than a single cell.

Answer (score 39):

**Is it possible to perform surgery on yourself?**

[Leonid Rogozov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Rogozov), when based on a Russian Antarctic base as doctor, was forced to perform appendix operation on himself.

> On the morning of 29 April 1961, Rogozov experienced general weakness, nausea, and moderate fever, and later pain in the lower right portion of the abdomen. None of the possible conservative treatment measures helped. By 30 April signs of localised peritonitis became apparent, and his condition worsened considerably by the evening. Mirny, the nearest Soviet research station, was more than 1,600 km (1,000 mi) from Novolazarevskaya. Antarctic research stations of other countries did not have an aircraft. Severe blizzard conditions prevented aircraft landing in any case. Rogozov had no option but to perform the operation on himself.
>
> The operation started at 02:00 local time on 1 May with the help of a driver and meteorologist, who were providing instruments and holding a mirror to observe areas not directly visible, while Rogozov was in a semi-reclining position, half-turned to his left side. A solution of 0.5% novocaine was used for local anaesthesia of the abdominal wall. Rogozov made a 10–12 cm incision of the abdominal wall, and while opening the peritoneum he accidentally injured the cecum and had to suture it. Then he proceeded to expose the appendix. According to his report, the appendix was found to have a dark stain at its base, and Rogozov estimated it would have burst within a day. The appendix was resected and antibiotics were applied directly into the peritoneal cavity. General weakness and nausea developed about 30–40 minutes after the start of the operation so that short pauses for rest were repeatedly needed after that. By about 04:00 the operation was complete.
>
> After the operation gradual improvement occurred in the signs of peritonitis and in the general condition of Rogozov. Body temperature returned to normal after five days, and the stitches were removed seven days after the operation. He resumed his regular duties in about two weeks.

So, it seems that is should be possible, with adequate preparation, to perform self surgery.

**Is it possible to perform surgery by yourself on your spine?**

But in the above case the abdomen is accessible with the hands with no big hurdles. Accessing the back region is going to be more cumbersome, especially considering the unnatural posture of the hands and the elbow when operating on oneself's back, if the operation has to be executed by hands.

If instead your character has the necessary tools for performing tele-surgery (basically remotely controlled robotic arms and hands), it should be feasible.

[image: robotic surgery]

The visor needs to be adapted to a laying position and of course the subject cannot undergo total anesthesia, but only local anesthesia shall be applied. Moreover, considering that the back will be cut open to access the spine, movement of the arms shall be prevented and the tools shall be operated only by finger movement.

Comment: Same question I gave to Cyn: do you have an example of anyone operating on their own back?  Two mirrors, hands upside down, elbows bent in the wrong direction.  I'm highly dubious.

Comment: it sounds like they need more than one doctor in Antarctica.

Comment: @JBH, as I stated, accessing your back with only hands is going to be cumbersome at least. That's why I suggested remotely controlled operation, where remotely means "use a visor and some controllers to operate the arms working on your back".

Comment: @theRiley The wintering crew at Antarctic bases is small (10-14).  Adding another doctor for the very few cases you need it is not worth it.  (Also, if you are going to have a duplicate doctor "just in case", you really need a duplicate diesel mechanic too - the diesel generator which produces the base's electricity *and heating* is pretty damn important.)

Comment: The [original case report](http://corpus.leeds.ac.uk/serge/rogozov-1964.pdf) is *very much* worth a read, BTW. His use of the first and third person to describe the doctor and the patient, and his commendation of *his assistants'* "stamina and presence of mind", are a masterpiece of dry humor.

Comment: While the efforts were heroic, an appendectomy is not the same thing as a spinal implantation procedure. Also, he had help! So that doesn't really answer the question. I don't think a robotic surgery device will improve matters. That just complicates what's already impossible. Every manoeuvre she makes will cause stabbing, burning pains. I doubt she's be able to control the device without causing herself more harm.

Answer (score 39):

## Yes, this is possible.

Here are some real-life examples:

[**Woman carries out caesarean on herself - and she and baby live**](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/apr/07/health.healthandwellbeing)

> A pregnant woman in Mexico is reported to have given birth to a
>   healthy baby boy after performing a caesarean section on herself with
>   a kitchen knife...The unidentified 40-year-old [other sources give her name as Ines Ramirez Perez], who lives in a rural
>   area without electricity, running water or sanitation, and whose home
>   was an eight-hour drive from the nearest hospital, performed the
>   operation when she found she could not deliver the baby naturally.
>
> She took three small glasses of hard liquor and, using a kitchen
>   knife, sliced her abdomen in three attempts ... and delivered a male
>   infant who breathed immediately and cried...Before losing
>   consciousness the woman told one of her children to call a local nurse
>   for help. After the nurse stitched the wound with a sewing needle and
>   cotton thread, the mother and baby were transferred and treated...at
>   the nearest hospital."

[**Doctor rescued from Antarctica in 1999 dies at 57**](http://www.cnn.com/2009/HEALTH/06/23/obit.jerri.nielsen/index.html)

> Dr. Jerri Nielsen...treated herself for breast cancer while stationed
>   at the South Pole in 1999...Nielsen caught the nation's attention in
>   1999, when she found a lump in her breast as a 47-year-old physician
>   stationed at the Amundsen-Scott South Pole Research Station. After
>   finding the lump in June, she diagnosed herself with breast cancer and
>   began treating herself using chemotherapy agents that the U.S. Air
>   Force parachuted to the station the next month.
>
> It was later revealed...that Nielsen -- an emergency room doctor from
>   Cleveland, Ohio -- performed a biopsy on herself with the help of
>   non-medical crew, who practiced using needles on a raw chicken.

In your character's case, the surgery is something from the future so hopefully, the tools are too.  She'd be unlikely to be able to reach her spine properly but even today we have robots that do surgery and can be controlled by computer.  So she could do that.

Imagine [robotic surgery](http://med.nyu.edu/robotic-surgery/physicians/what-robotic-surgery), for example (and this is modern day; in the OP's world, the tools would be higher tech).

And imagine an operating version of this:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of anyone performing surgery on their own spine?  It's comparatively easy when you don't have to reach behind you, use two mirrors, and operate with your hands upside down and backward.

Comment: No, but I do have this (and this is modern day; in the OP's world, the tools would be higher tech): https://med.nyu.edu/robotic-surgery/physicians/what-robotic-surgery

Comment: I'll grant you robotic surgery... but that negates the purpose of the question.  It's no longer the surgeon operating on his or her own back.

Comment: The person would still be performing the surgery.  I edited my answer to show a picture.   The robotic arm is just a tool, like a scalpel.  But instead of controlling it with your arm and fingers, you control it with a computer (using your arm and fingers).

Comment: I still contend that the use of robotics negates the purpose of the question as-written (the OP did not specify the existence or non-existence of robotics).  You bet, you can operate on any aspect of your body if you have robotics and a good camera (you wouldn't even have to lay down).  If the OP edits his/her question to state that robotics exist in the environment, I'll return the downvote.

Comment: I'll leave it to the OP to state if robotic arms under the complete control of the surgeon aka patient are fair game.  But I'll also say that, for a non-complicated insertion of a microchip, this could be done by a reasonably flexible person and a monitor (the question specifically says "she has all the surgery tools and a screen to watch what she is doing").  She's not operating *on* her spine, just near it.

Comment: reach behind your back and pretend to make an incision that is rather deep. focusing on what your doing while watching the screen so you do it properly. you have tweezers in the other and and you simple  place the micro chip into your spine.( then here comes the futuristic tecnology) you use a glue gun like object that seals it up.

Comment: @JBH I think you're incorrectly conflating "robotics" with "automation". The robotics means that the arms holding the tools aren't physically your arms. Without automation, you're still controlling them directly. It's easy to imagine a haptic suit of some kind, maybe with a VR helmet, that allows the arms but doesn't have the automation. Indeed, I could see those happening in our world quite easily -- robots are much easier to sterilize than humans, their arms never shake from exhaustion, and they can have all the tools in their hands much quicker than us mere humans.

Comment: @NicHartley, Actually, I'm not conflating them at all.  Read the OP's comment immediately above yours.  He's not assuming robotics or automation.  Indeed, other than replacing my set of double mirrors with a screen, he really is assuming arms behind back as I have been.  None of the answers here answered his question from that perspective, and I still believe the answer is "no."

Comment: @JBH I wasn't talking about OP's idea, I was talking about the answer I commented on.

Comment: @NicHartley, huh?  What's the point of commenting on an answer if it's outside the context of the OP?  I'm not questioning the idea that, given enough circumstance, the operation could be performed.l  I'm questioning whether or not this answer is *relevant* because it's outside the OP's scope.  (It appears a LOT of people have made the same mistake you have.  I feel bad for the OP.  His question is basically been hijacked.)

Comment: @JBH. I *have* answered the question. I said that a reasonably flexible person could reach behind her back and do the motions the OP stated as required. As long as there is a screen (or double mirrors, though they are harder). The OP stated outright that all you need is an incision, dropping the chip in with tweezers, then gluing yourself up.  I'd add cleaning the site before and after. That is doable for anyone without shoulder problems, plus size, or severe unflexibility (I deal with all 3 and *I* could do the reaching part if it's cervical or lumbar, and maybe some parts of the thoracic).

Comment: @Cyn -- With all due respect, the OP is not a surgeon and clearly has no clue what surgery in general, let alone spinal surgery, actually involves. A knife and "tweezers" is literally the first 35 seconds of the procedure. And no, you don't just "drop" an implant in with the tweezers. Your examples, while interesting, really don't answer the question. In both instances you cite the person in question had help. A kitchen c-section is possible. But notice that the lady passed out! That's not successful! A nurse had to come in and stitch her up and get her to hospital! Gross underestimation.

Comment: The OP really does need to give more information.  "The technology is futuristic" can mean anything.  I can only answer based on what the OP says...and if one cut, dropping it in, and glue is possible in her/his world, then this is workable.  If it's more like the surgery elemtilas detailed then, no, there's no way in hell.  Probably we all should have closed the question until it was better outlined.  So yeah, you're all right about modern-day reality, if the surgery is more than a simple chip install (like for pets).

Comment: @JBH This answer suggests robotic surgery. I was commenting on the idea of robotic surgery. I'm not sure why that's so confusing to you. It's very simple.

Comment: The biggest limitation of robotic surgery is whether or not the anaesthetic causes the character to lose control of her hands.  It's definitely plausible if the chip can be inserted in the lower back, but if it's at the base of the neck, you may struggle to control the pain without some loss of dexterity

Answer (score 10):

All in all, it's pretty unrealistic. Then again, if it's SciFi, why not.

Even the documented real cases where people have (allegedly) done surgery on themselves are for the most part somewhere in between *"fucking heroic"* and *"unbelieveable"*.

I am not going to say it's all lies, but as someone who performed that kind of intervention (on others, in proper conditions) for a living 15 years ago, the idea of e.g. operating your own appendix seems like something that's, well let's just say not very likely to succeed unless you are some kind of superhuman (or credible, for that matter).

Taking Rogozov as an example. With nothing but local anaesthetic, your belly will be hard as rock as soon as you cut in, let alone touch the peritoneum (with muscle relaxant on the other hand side, good luck operating or breathing). Speaking of which... the sensation of touching, or cutting through your peritoneum (which is not under local anaesthetic) is a sensation worth having. Imagine being on a football field, and one of those meatbags taking a 20-meter charge, then kicking you in the crown jewels, as hard as he can. That's approximately the feeling of cutting in your peritoneum. Staying conscious and actually doing something that requires delicate manual work for an entire 20 minutes after that? Well, kudos on being a real tough guy, Mr. Rogozov. But I'm more inclined to believe this is a case of Korsakoff, no offense intended.
Also it's worth to note that local anaesthetics are ineffective in acidic environment such as... oh wait, an inflammated appendix. Then there's that thing about accidentially cutting open the caecum and suturing it. And yes, not only living to tell, but going to work again after only two weeks. I've seen 22 year olds spending a week struggling for their lives with peritonitis in the ICU after having one of those  incidents. And that was in the early 2000s, consuming a 5-digit sum of care and antibiotics. This the kind of incident that, no matter how big your balls are, gives you cold sweat when you're an experienced surgeon. Let alone someone in 1960 who graduated a year earlier and is doing the operation on himself lying on his back. I mean, sure, when you're desperate and have few choices you probably try everything, but seriously... that's so fucking awesome superhuman that its factual accurracy is hard to believe.

But even if we assume the accounts are totally true and accurate -- the fact that one person did it and survived does not mean it is "doable" (in a sense that you can do it and expect to live). That's like saying Mrs. Vulović survived a fall from 10,000 meters (when in reality, she didn't fall at all), so it's *doable* to fall without parachute from 10,000 meters. Well, go ahead and try, no worries, you will always arrive on the ground.

As for the question's details:

> clean stable environment and there is no risk of infection
>   surgery near her spine [...] inserting a microchip connecting to the nerve connected to the brain

So basically, cut through the skin and open the liquid-filled spinal canal which rules out "no risk of infection".
Then insert a foreign body that connects to a single nerve connected to the brain. Well, far down in the cauda that would probably even be doable (if this still counts as "connected to the brain", which is technically not the case, being the lower motoneuron) but further up the spine where you find the real "connected to brain" neurons, good luck cutting open the bundle and fiddling with it without accidentially pulling an axon or two (or ten) and provoking a jerk with devastating results.
All that over a monitor via remote manipulators (unless you are a Chinese acrobat of sorts?). Uh. Well sure, while at it, why not transplant your head onto a different body.

Unless you consider some very, very tough SciFi voodoo (AI assisted half-robotic remote manipulators with, I don't know... force fields, super awesome nanobots, engineered bacteria that keep the skin barrier but refuse to grow in spinal fluid, bacta-tanks that magically cure everything, whatever?) I don't think this can be done, realistically. Not with any chance of success anyway.

Comment: Thanks for injecting a bit of humour into the answer!

Comment: Well, I guess that blows away my idea of cutting in from the front instead of the back. Unless "all the surgery tools" includes some sort of ventilator.

Comment: @MarkHu -- Oh, she can certainly do spine surgery from the front! All she has to do is hold her own intestines out of the way for hours on end while she digs around in there. Or she can also pretend to be a thoracic surgeon and collapse her own lung while she digs around up above.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like the most difficult part would be actually reaching around to to insert the microchip if it's behind her own back. With a local anaesthetic, she'd be able to make the incision and insert the chip. Obviously I can't speak to the extent of the futuristic technology, or how involved the surgery is, but a simple insertion certainly wouldn't be too hard.

You might be interested in reading about a Russian doctor called [Leonid Rogozov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Rogozov). He was the lone physician on an Antarctic expedition when he developed appendicitis. With no other options he gave himself a local anaesthetic and performed a self-appendectomy.
In his case he did have assistance in the form of a driver and meteorologist, but he made a full recovery and resumed his duties about a week later.

Another related topic would be [biohackers or grinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinder_(biohacking)), which is a term for people who experiment with cybernetic implants upon themselves. An example would be inserting small silicon-coated magnets under the fingertips, which can give the person a primitive electromagnetic sense as the magnet twitches and pushes against the nerve endings in the presence of an electrical field.

Comment: Aaaand finally, same question I asked Cyn and L.Dutch.  Do you have an example of anyone operating on their own back?  Two mirrors, hands upside down, elbows bent in the wrong direction....  I find it very hard to believe.

Comment: What mirrors?  The question says "screen."

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know of anyone performing an operation on their own back. From the question I would assume she has a camera and a screen in front of her so she can watch what she's doing. Depending on where the chip has to go - middle of the back would be difficult, but back of the neck may be simpler.

Comment: Considering that she needs to connect the chip to the "nerve that connects to the brain" (the spinal cord), I don't think just shoving a chip into a random spot on her back will accomplish anything. The surgery to do what the OP is asking is extremely involved. If it were just a matter of injecting a remote chip, then she could do that into the subcutaneous fat on her abdomen somewhere and call it a day!

Answer (score 0):

So if the technology is futuristic then why should she perform surgery herself. Let the future create a smart surgical pod that is capable of doing any kind of surgery. Just select a surgery and proceed and the computer is smart enough to finish the surgery with perfection.

I remember the surgery scene from the film [*Prometheus*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1446714/).

Answer (score 0):

Using current technology I agree with the answers saying that this is not possible.

My suggestion would be to have the chips specially made and equipped with nano-technology for this purpose though. All she has to do is make a cut near her spine and slide the chip in. It will automatically activate once inside and extend nano-fibres to penetrate the spine and connect itself.

This makes the required surgery much simpler and safer to the point that it becomes a lot more believable.